# Connection error using Python wrapper for Stanford CoreNLP tools v3.4.1

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I have been trying to use stanford-corenlp-python which is a python wrapper using [this](https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python) github repo.

However, while storing the results I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 14, in <module>
    result = nlp.parse("Hello world!  It is so beautiful.")
  File "client.py", line 11, in parse
    return json.loads(self.server.parse(text))
  File "/home/kenden/deeshacodes/stanford-corenlp-python/jsonrpc.py", line 934, in __call__
    return self.__req(self.__name, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/kenden/deeshacodes/stanford-corenlp-python/jsonrpc.py", line 906, in __req
    raise RPCTransportError(err)
jsonrpc.RPCTransportError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

How do I solve this? Also, is there any other way to use coreNLP in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try this [stanfordcorenlp](https://github.com/Lynten/stanford-corenlp).

It's very simple.

```
from stanfordcorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP

nlp = StanfordCoreNLP(r'G:/JavaLibraries/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31/')

sentence = 'Guangdong University of Foreign Studies is located in Guangzhou.'
print 'Tokenize:', nlp.word_tokenize(sentence)
print 'Part of Speech:', nlp.pos_tag(sentence)
print 'Named Entities:', nlp.ner(sentence)
print 'Constituency Parsing:', nlp.parse(sentence)
print 'Dependency Parsing:', nlp.dependency_parse(sentence)
```

Although convient, it is not as stable as native Python wrapper. "The project is just a wraper to parse the json data requested from the Java Server backend."

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a non-answer, but have you considered using the CoreNLP server? For example, [here](https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp) or [here](https://github.com/hhsecond/corenlp_pywrap)? You can also directly make requests to a running server and get JSON responses: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html (or protobuf, if you're feeling adventurous).